# NativeScript ListView with button tapEvent using data binded function

Tags: nativescript

I have a listview (code below), in the listview there is a `Button` with a `tap` event. I am trying to bind the function from my view-model code. The basic flow is the same as the typescript template for nativescript apps. However, this doesn't work because it's not a property of the *items* bound to the listview. I don't want to move the binded function outside of the view-model. I can't be the only crazy person doing something like this :P

```
   <ListView.itemTemplate>
    <GridLayout backgroundImage="{{ whatever }}" rows="auto, auto, auto" columns="70, *, auto">
      <Label row="0" col="1" text="{{ title }}" color="{{ whatever }}" class="feed-title" textWrap="true" />
      <Button text="&#xf397;" row="0" col="2" color="{{ whatever }}" tap="{{ moreOptionsTap }}" class="ionicon" />         
    </GridLayout>
  </ListView.itemTemplate>
```

Ignore the incorrect listview template, I stripped out a bunch of stuff to make this readable.

Answer (score 4):

Well forget the question, don't know why I didn't think to try what I was already doing inside the ListView on some other components. Docs here: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#binding-to-a-parent-binding-context

```
tap="{{ $parents['ListView'].moreOptionsTap }}"
```